# How to make a one-sided (past values only) filter for statsmodels.api.tsa.seasonal_decompose

Tags: python, filter, time-series, statsmodels

statsmodels.api.tsa.seasonal_decompose has a scarce documentation, and with regards to the filter option 'filt' it only mentions that it uses a two-sided filter.

I am working on time series and I would like to use a filter only using past values, so my model doesn't mistakenly use any future information. The filt option says it receives an 'array-like' argument only. What type of array argument would you use for the filter to be one-sided using a set number of past values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html), it looks like you can do what you want by passing `two_sided=False` to `seasonal_decompose`.